# template-toolkit: passing array variables into tpage from command line?

Tags: perl, templates, command-line, template-toolkit

I have this template working correctly:

```
$ cat matrix.tt 
[% DEFAULT
    ncols = 3
    elems = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
%]
\left[\begin{matrix}
[% WHILE elems.size %]
    [% elems.splice(0,ncols).join(' & ') %]
    [% IF elems.size %]\\[% END %]
[% END %]
\end{matrix}\right]
$ tpage --pre_chomp --post_chomp matrix.tt 
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3\\4 & 5 & 6\\7 & 8 & 9\end{matrix}\right]
```

But this does not work:

```
$ tpage --define ncols=2 --define elems=[1,2,3,4] matrix.tt 
undef error - WHILE loop terminated (> 1000 iterations)
```

I found using the following code that it is not trivial to pass arrays using the `--define` option to `tpage`.

```
$ cat pk.tt 
[% DEFAULT 
    ho = [1,2]
-%]
ho is [% ho %]
po is [% po %]
$ tpage --define po=[1,3] pk.tt #I want po to be interpreted as an array
ho is ARRAY(0x1a3fd00)
po is [1,3]
```

The output shows that po is a scalar. I want to pass arrays from command line is there any way to do that?

Comment: `tpage` can't do this: arguments to `--define` are treated as strings. You *can* hack the source, though. `tpage` is just a Perl script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to pass any data into `tpage` from command line without having to tweak `tpage` source or the template.

```
$ cat matrix.tt 
[% DEFAULT
    ncols = 3
    elems = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
%]
\left[\begin{matrix}
[% WHILE elems.size %]
    [% elems.splice(0,ncols).join(' & ') %]
    [% IF elems.size %]\\[% END %]
[% END %]
\end{matrix}\right]
$ cat <(echo '[% elems=["x","y","z",1,2,3] %]') matrix.tt |tpage --pre_chomp --post_chomp
\left[\begin{matrix}x & y & z\\1 & 2 & 3\end{matrix}\right]
$
```

or if you wish, you can *type in* a directive to set variables and press ^D:

```
$ rlwrap cat - matrix.tt |tpage --pre_chomp --post_chomp
[%
  ncols=4
  elems=[4,5,6,7,"x","y","z","t"]
%]
\left[\begin{matrix}4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\x & y & z & t\end{matrix}\right]
$
```

`rlwrap` saves the lines you type in, and makes them available later by pressing the `up` key. You can remove `rlwrap` if you do not need this.

The method works with any program that can process `stdin` given the shell supports this kind of redirection. I hope it is pretty portable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex the values in your array are, you might be able to get away with something like:

```
[%- el = elems.split(',') -%]
\left[\begin{matrix}
[% WHILE el.size %]
    [% el.splice(0,ncols).join(' & ') %]
... #etc

$ tpage --define ncols=2 --define elems="1,2,3,4" matrix.tt
```

But of course if `elems` is uncontrolled, or has embedded metacharacters or commas that might lead to pain. But otherwise it's simple enough to promote a scalar to an array using the `.split()` VMethod.

Comment: Thanks to show us how to use split() in the template

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments to `tpage` are not evaluated as Perl code, so you can only get string values. If you want to support arbitrary Perl code, you have to hack the `tpage` source.

---

Find the following line in the source:

```
my %ttopts   = $config->varlist('^template_(?!directive_)', 1);
```

On the next line, add the following code:

```
foreach my $var (keys %{ $ttopts{variables} }) {
    $ttopts{variables}{$var} = eval $ttopts{variables}{$var};
    die $@ if $@;
}
```

This loops through all of the arguments to `--define` and calls `eval` on them, converting them from strings to Perl code.

When you run this, make sure to quote your arguments to protect them from expansion by the shell:

```
$ ./tpage --define 'array=["foo","bar"]' --define 'hash={baz=>"qux"}' foo.tt

$VAR1 = [
          'foo',
          'bar'
        ];

$VAR1 = {
          'baz' => 'qux'
        };

$ cat foo.tt
[% USE Dumper %]
[% Dumper.dump(array) %]
[% Dumper.dump(hash) %]
```

To pass a literal string, you have to quote it with `q{}` or `qq{}` because [AppConfig](https://metacpan.org/pod/AppConfig) strips regular quotes (`tpage` uses AppConfig behind the scenes to read command line arguments). For example:

```
$ ./tpage --define 'string=q{foo}' foo.tt 

$VAR1 = 'foo';

$ cat foo.tt
[% USE Dumper %]
[% Dumper.dump(string) %]
```

Note that although Template Toolkit supports variables of just about any Perl type, my modified version of `tpage` doesn't. Numbers, strings, arrays, and hashes should all work; subroutines don't.